# I have three getlines, but once I compile, there are too many inputs

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string team1, team2, temp;
    int Days;

    cout << "Days: ";
    cin >> Days;

    int teamScore1[Days];
    int teamScore2[Days];

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "!";
    getline(cin, team1);

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "#";
    getline(cin, team2);

    cin.ignore();

    int i = 0;

    while(team1.length() > 0)
    {
        temp = team1.substr(0, team1.find(" "));
        stringstream(temp) >> teamScore1[i];
        i++;
    }
```

I'm just testing this code out, I have one cin, and 2 getlines but when I compile and run, there are more input prompts than I'm expecting. Thanks for the help in advance and sorry for the vague question, I don't really understand it enough to explain it.

Comment: team1 keeps being unempty endlessly in your code.

Comment: Are you sure your program is reading input and not hanging on the infinite loop at the end?

Comment: You're overusing `ignore`.

Comment: It is not going into the loop, It stays in asking for more inputs.

Comment: So I removed one ignore and it seems to be working fine. Can someone clarify how ignore works and when it should be used?

Comment: Remember that both `getline` and `ignore` consume newlines.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the `cin.ignore()` after the `getline`. If you remove both `cin.ignore()` the problem will be solved.

### More Detailed

If you check the c++ site for isstream::ignore it bascially says that  `cin.ignore()` will read a character from the input stream.

> **cin.ignore():** Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them, until either n characters have been extracted, or one compares equal to delim.
>   [C++ cin.ignore() Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

But the `getline()` will read the newline at the end of your input and discard it. So, when you execute `cin.ignore()` afterwards, it will expect something and wait therefore for another input.

> **getline():** If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded [C++ getline() Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

For example if you run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "HELLO";
}
```

It won't print the output until you type in something.

Hope that helps!